# Hide the menuBar in Camera capture dialog in windows mobile 6.5

Tags: .net, windows-mobile-6.5

I wanted to hide the menuBar in Camera capture dialog in windows mobile 6.5 development.

Answer (score 0):

there is no offical API to hide the menu bar of the Camera Capture Dialog. You may send keystrokes, message or a simple click to the dialog to get a fullscreen preview.

You may also be able to subclass the dialog and resize it to cover the menu bar. But this is not recommended. How should the user accept a taken picture or go back?

See also http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2011/03/08/mobile-development-subclassing-the-camera-view-cameracapturedialog-shcameracapture/

Leave a comment, if you can explain your need in more detail.

~josef

Comment: Hi Josef, Thanks for your reply. I wanted to hide the MENU in preview screen of camera capture dialogbox.     Thans in Advance

Comment: Hi Prem, then you have to send command to go in fullscreen mode of preview. Either by sending a tap inside the preview window or by issuing the menu command.

Comment: Hi Josef, Thanks a lot for your reply. Can u please give me the code. as i m very new to .net development

Comment: To start Pictures&Videos CameraDialog in FullScreen, change the following registry key to 0x01: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Pictures\Camera\USER]"FullScreen"=dword:00000000. But the dialo will toggle between full and normal screen mode each tim you tap into the live preview.